# How to search word under cursor using counsel-git-grep

Tags: search, counsel

I am using [`counsel-git-grep`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) to grep for a string in the current Git repository.

When I do `M-x counsel-git-grep` it opens following in the mini-buffer.

```
2    git grep:

3 chars more
```

---

Let say if the cursor on top of

```
def hello_word():
      ^
      |__cursor is here and when I entered `M-x counsel-git-grep`
```

I want following to open:

```
2    git grep: hello_word

3 chars more
```

[Q] How can I pass the word under cursor to the `counsel-git-grep` search?

Comment: Spacemacs has similar functionality, so maybe this helps you write a lisp function to do what you want? https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/2cdb535d0437a7023977883dc845ada48a05f213/layers/+completion/ivy/funcs.el#L190

Comment: ...in fact I see many functions in counsel.el also use `thing-at-point`, so quite likely that code would be useful if you were to implement this yourself.  From the code I don't see something that does it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrapped a couple of function in my dotemacs to achieve this:

```
;; from https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1068
(defun my-ivy-with-thing-at-point (cmd &optional dir)
  "Wrap a call to CMD with setting "
  (let ((ivy-initial-inputs-alist
         (list
          (cons cmd (thing-at-point 'symbol)))))
    (funcall cmd nil dir)))

(use-package counsel
  :config (setq counsel-ag-base-command "ag --vimgrep -a %s"))

(defun my-counsel-ag-from-here (&optional dir)
  "Start ag but from the directory the file is in (otherwise I would
be using git-grep)."
  (interactive "D")
  (my-ivy-with-thing-at-point
   'counsel-ag
   (or dir (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))))

(defun my-counsel-git-grep ()
  (interactive)
  (my-ivy-with-thing-at-point
   'counsel-git-grep))
```